# How to make keyboard stay when an alert box shows up?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to check if the value of a textfield is valid, if not, an alert box will pop up. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction) done: (id) sender{
    if (!test) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]init....];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else{
        [sender resignFirstResponder];
        //doing stuff;
    }
}
```

Currently the alert box works fine, but when I dismiss the alert box, the focus doesn't get back to the textfield that I specified. Any idea where I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement UIAlertView's `-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate method, which is called every time when alert view gets dismissed:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Yep. And if you have more than one text field, you can use UITextFieldDelegate to note which one is currently "holding the ball" and should be set as the firstResponder.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I reference this method? When I initialise the alert object, I set delegate=self, do I need to do some change? Or just put this method in the same file and it will get called every time I click cancel button?

Comment: Yes, `alertView.delegate = self` is enough to do this. Then, you insert this method in the same file.

Comment: that works! Thanks. And is there a way to remain the keyboard when I click the "Done" button on the keyboard?